# MySql Annotated Join in Ebean

Tags: java, mysql, orm, ebean

I am trying to create a join in Java. My issue is that although my query below returns exactly what I want in mySql I cannot get the data out of the ORM. In fact it appears that I am getting rows for Class A .... but my join is not working and the ArrayList of Class B rows is always Null.

Schema

```
tblA (aId)
tblB (bId,aId,bData1,bData2)

tblA.aId = tblB.aId
```

I have a query that I run directly in mySql that gives me what I need.

```
SELECT * FROM tblA a JOIN tblB b ON a.aId = b.aId WHERE a.aId = 
myNumber
```

I have the following classes

Class A

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="aId", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
ArrayList<ClassBRow> classBRows;

@Id
@Column(name="aId")
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long aId;
```

Class B

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="aId", referencedColumnName="aId")
private ClassA classARow;

@Id
@Column(name="bId")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer bId;

@Column(name"bData1")
private Integer bData1;

@Column(name"bData2")
private Integer bData2;
```

DriverClass

```
ClassARow classARow = mostEm.find(BidCountMasterRow.class, 
Long.parseLong(bidCountId));

Integer dailySum = 0;

if (classARow.classBRows !=null) {
     DO SOMETHING
}
```